# Measuring elapsed time in linux for a c program

Tags: c, linux, time

I am trying to measure elapsed time in Linux. My answer keeps returning zero which makes no sense to me. Below is the way i measure time in my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    double p16 = 1, pi = 0, precision = 1000;
    int k;
    unsigned long micros = 0;
    float millis = 0.0;
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    // This section calculates pi
    for(k = 0; k <= precision; k++)
    {
        pi += 1.0 / p16 * (4.0 / (8 * k + 1) - 2.0 / (8 * k + 4) - 1.0 / (8 * k + 5) - 1.0 / (8 * k + 6));
        p16 *= 16;
    }
    end = clock();
    micros = end - start;
    millis = micros / 1000;
    printf("%f\n", millis); //my time keeps being returned as 0

    printf("this value of pi is  : %f\n", pi);
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean the code is between the calls to `clock()`

Comment: refer to http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html

Comment: @UmNyoben I have just updated the code to show what is in between it.The problem i am having is the time keeps returning as 0

Comment: what about the gnu `time` program? or, alternatively, the bash command `time`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with you need to use floating point arithmetics. Any integer value divided by a larger integer value will be zero, always.

And of course you should actually *do* something between getting the start and end times.

---

By the way, if you have access to [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday) it's normally preferred over `clock` as it has higher resolution. Or maybe [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) which has even higher resolution.

Comment: Thank you .Would  you have any link for getimeofday

Comment: @Jackwelch, there is no excuse not to use the `man` command on linux.

Comment: @Jackwelch Updated the answer with links to the function manual pages.

Comment: If I may ask you a quick question.How do you measure elapsed time on linux machines

Comment: @Jackwelch Like you do in your question. Get the start time, do some work, get the end time, and calculate the difference. The actual functions and structures involved doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It still does not work.I have just updated my code above.The time keeps getting returned as 0

Comment: @Jackwelch You still do integer division! Change to `millis = micros / 1000.0f;`

Comment: @Jack, using bash, executables can be timed with **time**

Comment: @BrianTiffin `time` as in the _function_ or as in the _shell command_? If the first it has to coarse resolution, if the second it's only for the whole program when running in a shell and not for part of a program.

Comment: @Joachim;  I was thinking about the bash builtin, and really only in the context of 'How do you measure elapsed time on linux machines".  Could have mentioned valgrind and/or gprof I guess.

Answer (score 22):

Three alternatives

1. `clock()`
2. `gettimeofday()`
3. `clock_gettime()`

`clock_gettime()` goes upto nanosecond accuracy and it supports 4 clocks.

- **CLOCK_REALTIME**

  System-wide realtime clock. Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges.
- **CLOCK_MONOTONIC**

  Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point.
- **CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID**

  High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU.
- **CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID**

  Thread-specific CPU-time clock.

You can use it as

```
#include <time.h>

struct timespec start, stop;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);

/// do something

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &stop);

double result = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e6 + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e3;    // in microseconds
```

Answer (score 8):

Note: The clock() function returns CPU time for your process, not wall clock time.  I believe this is what the OP was interested in.  If wall clock time is desired, then gettimeofday() is a good choice as suggested by an earlier answer.  clock_gettime() can do either one if your system supports it; on my linux embedded system clock_gettime() is not supported, but clock() and gettimeofday() are.

Below is the code for getting wall clock time using gettimeofday()

```
#include <stdio.h> // for printf()
#include <sys/time.h> // for clock_gettime()
#include <unistd.h> // for usleep()

int main() {
    struct timeval start, end;
    long secs_used,micros_used;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    usleep(1250000); // Do the stuff you want to time here
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    printf("start: %d secs, %d usecs\n",start.tv_sec,start.tv_usec);
    printf("end: %d secs, %d usecs\n",end.tv_sec,end.tv_usec);

    secs_used=(end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec); //avoid overflow by subtracting first
    micros_used= ((secs_used*1000000) + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_usec);

    printf("micros_used: %d\n",micros_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code as written.

1. According to `man 3 clock`, the resolution of `clock()` is in `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` increments per second.  On a recent-ish Cygwin system, it's 200.  Based on the names of your variables, you are expecting the value to be 1,000,000.
2. This line:

   ```
   millis = micros / 1000;
   ```

   will compute the quotient as an integer, because both operands are integers.  The promotion to a floating-point type occurs at the time of the assignment to `millis`, at which point the fractional part has already been discarded.

To compute the number of seconds elapsed using `clock()`, you need to do something like this:

```
clock_t start, end;
float seconds;
start = clock();
// Your code here:
end = clock();
seconds = end - start; // time difference is now a float
seconds /= CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // this division is now floating point
```

However, you will almost certainly not get millisecond accuracy.  For that, you would need to use `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`.  Further, you probably want to use `double` instead of `float`, because you are likely going to wind up subtracting very large numbers with a very tiny difference.  The example using `clock_gettime()` would be:

```
#include <time.h>
/* Floating point nanoseconds per second */
#define NANO_PER_SEC 1000000000.0

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec start, end;
    double start_sec, end_sec, elapsed_sec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    // Your code here
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    start_sec = start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec / NANO_PER_SEC;
    end_sec = end.tv_sec + end.tv_nsec / NANO_PER_SEC;
    elapsed_sec = end_sec - start_sec;
    printf("The operation took %.3f seconds\n", elapsed_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

Since `NANO_PER_SEC` is a floating-point value, the division operations are carried out in floating-point.

Sources:
`man` pages for `clock(3)`, `gettimeofday(3)`, and `clock_gettime(3)`.
*The* *C* *Programming* *Language*, Kernighan and Ritchie

Comment: end_sec = end.tv_sec + end.tv_n_sec/NANO_PER_SEC; would be:
end_sec = end.tv_sec + end.tv_nsec / NANO_PER_SEC;

Answer (score 1):

When you divide, you might end up with a decimal, hence you need a flaoting point number to store the number of milli seconds.
If you don't use a floating point, the decimal part is truncated. In your piece of code, the start and end are ALMOST the same. Hence the result after division when stored in a long is "0".

```
unsigned long micros = 0;
float millis = 0.0;
clock_t start, end;

start = clock();

//code goes here

end = clock();

micros = end - start;
millis = micros / 1000;
```

Comment: Try using the micro seconds. Your code might be taking very little time to execute for you to measure it in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try Sunil D S's answer but change micros from unsigned long to type float or double, like this:

```
double micros;
float seconds;

clock_t start, end;

start = clock();

/* Do something here */

end = clock();

micros = end - start;
seconds = micros / 1000000;
```

Alternatively, you could use rusage, like this:

```
struct rusage before;

struct rusage after;

float a_cputime, b_cputime, e_cputime;

float a_systime, b_systime, e_systime;

getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);

/* Do something here! or put in loop and do many times */

getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

a_cputime = after.ru_utime.tv_sec + after.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

b_cputime = before.ru_utime.tv_sec + before.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

e_cputime = a_cputime - b_cputime;

a_systime = after.ru_stime.tv_sec + after.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

b_systime = before.ru_stime.tv_sec + before.ru_stime.tv_usec / 1000000.0;

e_systime = a_systime - b_systime;


printf("CPU time (secs): user=%.4f; system=%.4f; real=%.4f\n",e_cputime, e_systime, seconds);
```

Units and precision depend on how much time you want to measure but either of these should
provide reasonable accuracy for ms.